# Cookie encoding

Tags: firefox, cookies, google-chrome

I have a problem with cookie encoding. The cookies have some French character inside them.  Firefox sends them back correctly, but it seems Chrome has problem with sending them.
Any idea why it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Chrome doesn't support Unicode in its cookies :-/

Comment: Cookies are transmitted in the HTTP header; it is restricted to ASCII only. Some browsers will send illegal data; others will silently drop it. There is no standard way to encode cookies but percent-encoding is generally used. See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to

1. convert the french string to UTF-8 and then
2. do percent encoding (also known as URL encoding) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

This way you can submit any Unicode string via Cookie.

In C# there is a function that does exactly these both things: `System.Uri.EscapeDataString()`